# Laravel 4 - using php with laravel code blocks to get selected state

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This may be quite simple but not sure how to get round it.  I need to get selected state for my multiple select list.  It is used as part of a search filter. The last php line grabs the values for my fruit from a querystring.

```
<select data-placeholder="Select fruit ..." name="fruit[]" id="fruit" multiple>

   @foreach (Fruit::where('active',1)->orderBy('title')->get() as $fruit)

         <option value="{{ $fruit->id }}">{{ $fruit->title }}</option>

   @endforeach

</select>
<?php if(isset($_GET["fruit"]))  echo implode(',', $_GET["fruit"]); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should pass the `data/array` from your controller instead of using database query in your view, for example:

```
// In your controller's method

$fruits = Fruit::where('active',1)->orderBy('title')->lists('title', 'id');

// Load the view and pass the fruits
return view::make('view_name')->with('fruits', $fruits)
                              ->with('selected', Input::get('fruit'));
```

Then in the `view` try this:

```
echo Form::select(
         'fruit[]',
         $fruits,
         $selected,
         array(
             'data-placeholder' => 'Select fruit ...',
             'id' => 'fruit'
         )
    );
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would actually cause an error, as you've passed an instance of `Collection` into the `Form::select()` rather than an array.

Comment: Used this and it works perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help and giving me insight into how to best use Laravel to my advantage for this kind of task.  I'm still a bit of a newbie.

Comment: I wonder if I could trouble you for one small query.  How would I add another list element to my View::make?

Comment: You can add as many as you want, probably you should tell me more about your query @user3189734.

Comment: I've added vegetables but it doesn't work although fruit still works good.  return View::make('view_name')->with('fruits', $fruits)->with('vegetables', $vegetables)->with('selected', Input::get('fruits'), Input::get('vegetables') );

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest way to achieve this, would be to do as follows.

Controller method:

```
// Assuming that $_GET['fruit'] is the id
$fruit = Input::get('fruit', null); // $_GET['fruit'] basically

// This is better for selects as it provides a key => value array
$fruits = Fruit::where('active', 1)->orderBy('title')->lists('title', 'id');

return View::make('view_name', compact('fruit', 'fruits'));
```

In your actual view, assuming use of blade:

```
{{ Form::select('fruit', $fruits, $fruit ['data-placeholder' => 'etc etc..']) }}
```

There we go. Nice a clean code, short and sweet, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank Ollie for your input. It is equally valid and helps me understand a cleaner way of constructing controller led form elements.